# Calendar on Windows 10 - delete specific instance of a recurring event?

Tags: windows-10, calendar

I am using the built-in calendar that comes with Windows 10 and is accessible from the taskbar.

I have a recurring event every Wednesday. How can I delete one specific instance of that event without deleting the whole event? The delete button doesn't offer any helpful options like "delete only this event" or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running version 16005.12527.20152.0 I just added a test event with a weekly recurrence, and when I right-click the event and go to Delete I see

[image]

Do you not see those options?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I see these options now, but I never tried right-clickling the event in the calendar view. I was trying to delete event from the event itself and these options weren't present there.

Comment: No problem, have a great day.